# RealUrl conflict on multidomain pages with the same name

Tags: typo3, realurl

I get a conflict in `EXT:realUrl` because of a page with the same name in both domains.

- `domain.com/contact.html`
- `mobile.domain.com/contact.html`

**I got this setup:**

The realurl configuration in PHP both with their own `rootpage_id`:

> ['EXTCONF']['realurl']['_DEFAULT']
>       ['EXTCONF']['realurl']['mobile.domain.com']

TypoScript:

> config.baseURL = http://mobile.domain.com/
>      config.tx_realurl_enable = 1
>      config.typolinkCheckRootline = 1
>      config.typolinkEnableLinksAcrossDomains = 1
>      config.typolinkLinkAccessRestrictedPages = NONE
>      config.prefixLocalAnchors = all
>      config.content_from_pid_allowOutsideDomain = 1

Is there something missing in my configuration?
What could I do to solve the conflict?

Answer (score 0):

When you have following steps

#### Step 1

```
$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['EXTCONF']['realurl']['mobile.example.com'] = 
$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['EXTCONF']['realurl']['_DEFAULT'];
$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['EXTCONF']['realurl']['mobile.example.com']['pagePath']['rootpage_id'] = 999;
```

#### Step 2

Add Domain Entries on the rootpages

#### Step 3

Add setup condition

```
[globalString = IENV:HTTP_HOST=www.example.com]
config.baseURL = http://www.example.com/
[end]
```

#### Step 4

Clear all caches (realUrl caches inkl.)

Greetings

Comment: `$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['EXTCONF']['realurl']['mobile.example.com']` is set and rootpage_id is assigned.
Domain records exist on both root pages.
`config.baseURL` is set for both domains.
no luck so far, but thx for the respionse.